# What mammals that are commonly kept as pets can be kept healthy on a vegan diet?

Tags: diet, pet-selection

We know from [Can I feed my cat a vegetarian or vegan diet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/can-i-feed-my-cat-a-vegetarian-or-vegan-diet) that trying to force a [vegan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veganism) diet on some types of pets might not be healthy.

If someone is looking for pet, with a preference for a mammal that can be housebroken, with a naturally vegan diet (herbivorous), what common animals would they want to consider?

Comment: Animals are not vegan since that is a quasi-religious lifestyle choice.  They are herbivorous or plant eating but not vegan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only mammals you'd be able to keep healthy on a vegetarian diet would be rabbits, or rodents like gerbils, hamsters, mice, rats, guinea pigs, etc. They will all do fine on a diet of vegetables and grains.

If you have the means to, you could keep an exotic pet like a fruit bat. But I would stress that bats are high maintenance, might require a license depending on where you live, and aren't able to be housebroken. The first question you have to ask is are you willing to have a bat fly around your house all night?

Otherwise you'll want to look into animals like birds, fish, or even a select few reptiles.

Other mammals are either carnivore (all meat), omnivore (some meat), or insectivore (almost all insects).

Answer (score 4):

I would consider looking into a house rabbit - they are wonderfully engaging little critters, can be litter trained and enjoy veggies. However, they do take considerable care and research beforehand - I highly recommend http://rabbit.org/ (the House Rabbit Society) for helping you make your decision. We have three dwarf lops that we are just crazy about!