# Is this cat food harmful?

Tags: cats

I own a cat (a British shorthair). A few days ago I searched for cat food. I found a website that sells cat food, and I wanted to buy [this](https://www.petzzshop.com/royal-canin-british-shorthair-kitten-yavru-kedi-mamasi-2-kg) ('*Royal Canin British Shorthair Kitten cat food*'), but I looked into Royal Canin cat foods, and there are some people who say it is harmful for cats. Should I buy this or not? What food should I give my cat otherwise?

Comment: please add a link to where you found the information about the food.

Comment: the news was in Turkish, can you read it ?

Comment: We have some related questions with good answers here on StackExchange, if you're interested in the matter of cat food quality. [Grain-free Options for Preventing Struvite Crystal Formation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/24197/12501), [Is it possible to feed a cat a healthy meat diet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/23575/12501), [Why are grain-free cat foods filled with vegetables instead of more meat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/6359/12501), [Is there benefit to feeding my cats cat food that incorporates fruits and vegetables?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1885/12501)

Answer (score 3):

This food can cause some problems, but overall it's not worse than most dry foods.

- It has a lot of calories. That's good for kittens, because they're more active than adult cats, but if you feed this food to an adult cat, it would probably gain weight rather quickly.
- It has too much grain in it. Grains in cat food are known to cause kidney stones and urinary tract diseases. Unfortunately grain is much cheaper than meat, so most commercial cat foods (especially the cheap ones) contain a lot of grain.
- Some people (but not many) report that their cats vomit or get diarrhea after eating this food. This is to be expected, because some cats are more sensitive than others or have allergies.

So, in summary:

**This food is not ideal for cats and can cause medical problems in the long run,** but it's not worse than most cat foods. If you want good, healthy cat food, read the list of ingredients and only buy cat food without any grains (rice, maize/corn, wheat, oats, barley or rye).

Comment: I see, i wonder if cat food is really harmful