# Is spinach bad for cats?

Tags: cats, diet, vegetarian-food

My cat loves creamed spinach which I buy frozen. He eats that more enthusiastically than normal wet or dry cat food.

But recently I've learned that spinach is high in oxalate which is a main ingredient of kidney stones. I've also read that urinary tract obstruction is a main cause of suffering and death among cats. So I'm wondering if I should stop giving the cat spinach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spinach is low in calories and has high concentration of many minerals and vitamins. Spinach also contains glycoclycerolipids which helps protect the lining of the digestive tract from damage due to inflammation.

However, spinach also has small amounts of calcium oxalate which is known to cause stones in urinary tracts and kidneys.

Consumption of spinach sporadically and in small amounts should not be a cause of worry. It is rather a healthy diet if consumed in small amounts. But regular consumption should be avoided.

Also for cats with history of urinary and kidney problems, no consumption of spinach is advisable.

Also do consult your vet.

**SOURCE -**

[11 People Foods for Cats](https://moderncat.com/articles/11-people-foods-cats/)
[10 'People Foods' Cats Can Eat Too](https://mom.me/pets/17929-10-people-foods-cats-can-eat-too/item/can-cats-eat-spinach/)

**RELATED -**

[What are some green vegetables that I can safely feed to my cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21942/what-are-some-green-vegetables-that-i-can-safely-feed-to-my-cat/21943#21943)
[Is there benefit to feeding my cats cat food that incorporates fruits and vegetables?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/is-there-benefit-to-feeding-my-cats-cat-food-that-incorporates-fruits-and-vegeta)
[How to prepare vegetables to feed a cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21944/how-to-prepare-vegetables-to-feed-a-cat/21945#21945)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't give him a human-sized portion of spinach for the same reason the other poster stated.

But I will say that he probably just likes the cream. Most cats love the taste of anything dairy-related.

However, cats are lactose intolerant, so if you wanted to give him a special treat you could give him some goat milk every now and then.