# What are some green vegetables that I can safely feed to my cat?

Tags: cats, diet, vegetarian-food

I often see cats eating green leafy vegetables on youtube. So I was wondering what are some green leafy vegetables that I can safely feed to my cat without the risk of negative side effects.

Quoting proper sources would be  helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Although being obligate carnivores cats can't digest green leafy vegetables still it is essential part of their diet. See my answer in the post [Is there benefit to feeding my cats cat food that incorporates fruits and vegetables?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/is-there-benefit-to-feeding-my-cats-cat-food-that-incorporates-fruits-and-vegeta)

Coming to your question, below are some of the green leafy vegetables that can be safely fed to a cat -

- Steamed Broccoli
- Steamed Green Beans
- Steamed Asparagus
- Spinach *(Spinach has Calcium Oxalate which can form crystals in the urinary track and kidney. So spinach should not be fed regularly and not to cats with history of urinary and kidney problems)*
- Fresh or frozen peas

However some cats can be allergic to certain vegetables. So do consult your vet.

**SOURCE** -

[11 People Foods for Cats](https://moderncat.com/articles/11-people-foods-cats/)
[8 More People Foods For Cats](https://moderncat.com/articles/8-more-people-foods-cats/68598/)
[HUMAN FOOD FOR CATS: A BASIC GUIDE](https://www.worldsbestcatlitter.com/clearing-the-air/2016/08/human-food-for-cats-a-basic-guide/)
[10 'People Foods' Cats Can Eat Too](https://mom.me/pets/17929-10-people-foods-cats-can-eat-too/)
[Best Fruits and Vegetables for Cats](http://www.vetstreet.com/our-pet-experts/best-fruits-and-vegetables-for-cats)

**RELATED** -

[How to prepare vegetables to feed a cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21944/how-to-prepare-vegetables-to-feed-a-cat/21945#21945)