# Can cats survive on a diet composed of insects?

Tags: cats, diet

I saw in [This question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/can-i-feed-my-cat-a-vegetarian-or-vegan-diet)
that cats cannot survive on a vegan diets alone, but what if the diet included common insects? Such as crickets, grass hoppers and flies?

The reason I ask is in relation to Zootopia, which explain carnivore diets as based on insect 'burgers'.  [relevant question here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122725/what-do-the-carnivores-eat-in-the-zootopia-universe). As such I was wondering if this is a feasible solution in feline predators.

Comment: Could you add some more detail? Could you describe your cat please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless insects contain significant quantities of all the essential nutrients -- specifically including taurine, which is an essential amino acid for cats since they can't synthesize it -- the answer is no. Even if you could convince the cat to put up with that diet.

Cats are obligate carnivores. Don't try to make them anything else.

Comment: Since I doubt anyone has actually tried it, all I can do is recommend that you look up feline nutritional requirements -- which are fairly well documented, since pet food companies use that as a starting point -- and then research which insects, if any, have significant amounts thereof. But realistically, expecting a cartoon plot device to bear any resemblance to reality is both silly and missing the point.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4473169/ A paper on the topic found that all but one of the insect species tested can fulfill their nutrient requirements, but still I strongly recommend sticking to foods designed for your pet, rather than messing with unknowns that could severely harm your cat if you screw up. Don't get a cat as a pet if you have moral qualms about killing animals.

Answer (score 0):

My cat rarely eats his catfood , he very much prefers to eat bugs all day long! We live on 10 acres of land and he is obsessed with chasing and eating bugs his every waking hour! I have tried to keep him inside, and discourage his bug eating, but he just pouts and meows to go back out to chase and eat his bugs, so I keep food and water out for him at all times and just let him do his thing now.He is healthy and fit so I just have to accept that he is fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Looks like yes. Taurine content for insects varies widely; some are listed in this article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect-based_pet_food

Some insect-based cat foods:

https://usa.catit.com/shop/catit-nuna-insect-based/

https://www.lovebugpetfood.com/

https://www.yorapetfoods.com/yora-for-cats

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Thank you for the update of this old question! I can only guess, why others voted ypur answer down and want to delete it: Please delete the links to shops. Ypu can mention the brands in text as examples, but where to buy them the users want to choose themself. And please write some more about the general insect food. Maybe what your experiences with it are. Or how the insect food fulfils the challenges, like the discussed taurin.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29812)

Comment: just because there are such foods doesn't mean they're healthy. Sadly a LOT of packaged pet foods are NOT healthy long term for your pets. And wikipedia is notoriously unreliable, articles often highly dubious and based on the ideology of the authors and editors.