# List of vegetarian food for my Dog(Labra)

Tags: dogs

I Have a labra dog and I am a pure vegetarian person so that I want the list of vegetarian food for my dog, which helpful for dog health as well as disease.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I thought this might be a duplicate, but I don't find it for dogs only cats, see related [Can I feed my cat a vegetarian or vegan diet?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/can-i-feed-my-cat-a-vegetarian-or-vegan-diet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep there are options for canine vegetarian diets! 
You have the [royal canin vegetarian diet](https://www.royalcanin.com/products/royal-canin-veterinary-diet-canine-vegetarian-dry-dog-food-17.6-lb-bag/561717)

And also [Hilary's blend](http://completeandbalanced.com/recipebook.html) dog recipes have a few vegetarian options if you want to go home-made, these recipes are complete and balanced so your pet does not lack any nutrients. Your veterinarian could photocopy a few recipes, you will just have to buy the supplement powders that she provides.